# If $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1],$ then $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} f(\sin x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi}_{0} f(\sin x)dx.$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Since $\int^{\pi}_{0} f(\sin x)dx = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} f(\sin x)dx + \int^{\pi}_{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(\sin x)dx, $ it suffices to show $\int^{\pi}_{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(\sin x)dx = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} f(\sin x)dx.$ Let $u=\frac{\pi}{2} + x.$ Then, $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}f(\sin x)dx = \int^{\pi}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin(u-\frac{\pi}{2}))du.$ But $\sin(u-\frac{\pi}{2}) \neq \sin u$ on $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi ].$  So how do I proceed from here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put $y=\pi-x$  for $\displaystyle\int_{\frac\pi2}^\pi f(\sin x)dx$

$\implies \sin x=\sin(\pi - y)=\sin y$

and $y=0$ when $x=\pi$ and $y=\frac\pi2$ when $x=\frac\pi2$